# Mathematical operation on columns of two files

Tags: awk

I have a file with 2 columns. I would like to do the following operation:
Col1/ [ (1+0.214/(Col2*Col2))^2 ]. To do that I write an awk command:

```
awk '{print $1/(1+.214/($2*$2))*(1+.214/($2*$2))}' ab.txt > G1.txt
```

But I am getting the same numbers as column1 in the output. Could anyone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: use the exponent operator `^` to simplify the expression: awk '{print $1/(1+.214/($2*$2))^2}'

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no surprise that you get the same numbers again because there is one pair of parentheses missing. Look carefully at your expression! 
What you calculate is (y/x) * x (y divided by x multiplied by x). What you need is y/(x*x) or in other words

```
awk '{print $1/((1+.214/($2*$2))*(1+.214/($2*$2)))}' ab.txt > G1.txt
```

Don't worry! If i had gotten a penny for every missing parenthesis, ...